# Angular-Ui-Calendar: How to show two agendaWeekView in single calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am facing problem while adding two agendaWeekView in a single calendar. Please have a look the calendar config.

```
header:{
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek agendaWeek'
    },
```

here I am calling agendaWeek two times, It appears two tab in the calendar called "Week" but when I clicked anyone of them both views are activated and I am also not able to change the text of the week tabs. So please give some suggestion for it.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are not closing the right header variable with a quotation.

Maybe this will work.

```
header:{
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek agendaWeek'
},
```

Not sure though. If you could post a plunker of fiddle then we could diagnose with ease.

Comment: No it was just typing mistake... have you tried to duplicating the same view in the single calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can duplicate views or create own custom views in the single calenndar. Here is the solution. 
We need to change in the fullcalendar.js file.

1. Firstly add your custom view name, according to my question I wanted to duplicate agendaView so that's why my view name will be "duplicateAgendaWeek". Set the name into defaults.

   ```
   buttonText: {
   prev: "<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&lsaquo;</span>",
   next: "<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&rsaquo;</span>",
   prevYear: "<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&laquo;</span>",
   nextYear: "<span class='fc-text-arrow'>&raquo;</span>",
   today: 'today',
   month: 'month',
   week: 'Weekly',
   day: 'Daily',
   duplicateAgendaWeek: 'Duplicate Week' // here is the name of my view.
   ```

   },
2. Now duplicate the existing agendaWeek function with your view name.

   ```
   fcViews.duplicateAgendaWeek= DuplicateAgendaWeekView;

   function DuplicateAgendaWeekView(element, calendar) {
   var t = this;


   // exports
   t.render = render;


   // imports
   AgendaView.call(t, element, calendar, 'duplicateAgendaWeek');
   var opt = t.opt;
   var renderAgenda = t.renderAgenda;
   var formatDates = calendar.formatDates;



   function render(date, delta) {
   if (delta) {
       addDays(date, delta * 7);
   }
   var start = addDays(cloneDate(date), -((date.getDay() - opt('firstDay') + 7) % 7));
   var end = addDays(cloneDate(start), 7);
   var visStart = cloneDate(start);
   var visEnd = cloneDate(end);
   var weekends = opt('weekends');
   if (!weekends) {
       skipWeekend(visStart);
       skipWeekend(visEnd, -1, true);
   }
   t.title = formatDates(
       visStart,
       addDays(cloneDate(visEnd), -1),
       opt('titleFormat')
   );
   t.start = start;
   t.end = end;
   t.visStart = visStart;
   t.visEnd = visEnd;
   renderAgenda(weekends ? 7 : 5);
   }


   }

   ;;
   ```
3. Now the last one need to set formats for our custom views.

   ```
   // time formats
   titleFormat: {
   month: 'MMMM yyyy',
   week: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}",
   duplicateAgendaWeek: "MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}", // set your view format here
   day: 'dddd, MMM d, yyyy'
   },
   columnFormat: {
   month: 'ddd',
   week: 'ddd M/d',
   duplicateAgendaWeek: 'ddd M/d',// set your view format here
   day: 'dddd M/d'
   },
   ```
4. Now just call the view name from your controller.

   ```
     header:{
       left: 'prev,next',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'agendaDay agendaWeek duplicateAgendaWeek',
   },
   ```